# Redirect With Post data (json) and has headers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to redirect with a json data and has headers, I have tried jquery.redirect but I do not know how to put headers (like 'content-type': 'application/json') ...

This is my code :

```
$.redirect('url', data, 'POST', '_blank');
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You can't put headers in a browser initiated redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The only time you can specify HTTP request headers when using browser-side JavaScript is when you are using `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` (i.e. Ajax).

(You can also use `enctype` in a form submission, but not with `application/json` as the value).